# Location of logs of Groovy scripts at Bonita Studio - Community Edition Version : 5.9.1

Tags: bonita

I am reviewing some workflows at Bonita Studio - Community Edition Version : 5.9.1.

In some groovy scripts there are some `System.out.print()`. Where are these been printed when I execute the scripts? 
Cause they are not at Help->Show Log, nor at Help->Show engine log.

Also, is there any way to review the embeded code of connectors with a nice editor, e.g. eclipse, intelij?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard out of a Groovy script is not connected to the logs.
You need to use a logging system:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger ("com.mydomain.myapp");
logger.info("Something...");
```

Be sure to configure in logging.properties the correct logging level:

```
com.mydomain.myapp = FINE
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you for your answer on how to setup logger. Logs are placed at: 

`...\BonitaBPMCommunity-x.x.x\workspace\tomcat\server\logs`

and 

`...\BonitaBPMCommunity-x.x.x\workspace\.metadata`